# Where to find open source code for a .css left menu restricted by width

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for something open-source, similar to dynamicdrive.com, what they offer, since I'm  not too intelligent.  I have a vertical left menu.  I'd like to have submenus, such as:

```
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About us</li>
  <li>Products
     <li>Machine Vision Integration</li>
     <li>High Resolution Sensors</li>
     <li>Bead Detection</li>
  </li>
  <li>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
```

Basically, so when they hover over Products, then that exposes the submenu with the 3 particular products.  That's pretty simple.  Here's what's not (to me):

I'm restricted to a column width of 200 pixels.  So many of the menus I saw in Dynamic Drive, when you hover over, for instance, products, it expands WAY to the right, an extra 200 pixels, and when you try to click the submenu, it disappears, because you've exceeded your width.

But if I could find something that, when you hover over something that has a submenu, it doesn't expand TOO far to the right, so I won't take up the 200 pixels, I think that would work best.

Any links, suggestions, or guidance to point me in the right direction here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This should get you started http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... if you can't pass that limit, why not a **accordion menu**?

> http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ddaccordionmenu.htm

Comment: Hey Balexandre, thank you for that link.  Those are pretty cool!  I like 'em, and they seem pretty browser-friendly.  I think I found my answer just googling on the web, with the:

Comment: oops ... with the z-index:1; attribute.  The positive 1 puts it in front of other things, overlapping, where the -1 will keep it behind.  Thank you very much for the link to the accordions, though.  I bookmarked it and will use it!